# Mongodb: `com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream` with morphia

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, morphia

I've a simple data structure (the `Transaction` referenced below) to be inserted into mongodb:

```
{"amount":111,"debitAcc":"588188286231743e7d5c923d","type":"CHARGE"}
```

An I got the following error stack：

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:88)
        at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:494)
        at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:224)
        at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.receiveMessage(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:96)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.receiveMessage(DefaultConnectionPool.java:440)
        at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.receiveMessage(WriteCommandProtocol.java:262)
        at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.execute(WriteCommandProtocol.java:104)
        at com.mongodb.connection.InsertCommandProtocol.execute(InsertCommandProtocol.java:67)
        at com.mongodb.connection.InsertCommandProtocol.execute(InsertCommandProtocol.java:37)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:168)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:289)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.insertCommand(DefaultServerConnection.java:118)
        at com.mongodb.operation.InsertOperation.executeCommandProtocol(InsertOperation.java:76)
        at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation$1.call(BaseWriteOperation.java:139)
        at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation$1.call(BaseWriteOperation.java:133)
        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:422)
        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:413)
        at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:133)
        at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:60)
        at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:845)
        at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:828)
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.executeWriteOperation(DBCollection.java:342)
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:337)
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:328)
        at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.saveDocument(DatastoreImpl.java:1297)
        at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.tryVersionedUpdate(DatastoreImpl.java:1340)
        at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:1286)
        at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:775)
        at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:758)
```

My mongodb version is `3.4.2`.

Intereting is that I don't have the issue on my local dev environment (mint linux 18.1). But it just can't work on my SIT environment, which is a ubuntu 16.04

Any idea?

**Updates with code to insert the document**

[image]

Where `transactionDao.save(...)` implementation could be found at:

https://github.com/actframework/act-morphia/blob/master/src/main/java/act/db/morphia/MorphiaDaoBase.java#L206

**update 2**

The system works with other writes (even with much bigger records)

Comment: Where is the code you use to insert that document?

Comment: Do any other operations actually work in your SIT environment?

Comment: Yes other operations works as usual. This is why it bothers me a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the root cause, but in the end I get the issue fixed by changing a field type from `BigDecimal` to `double`.

The issue is found in our SIT environmet and one developer's windows environment which has a mongodb cluser setup.

Comment: DId you ever find the root cause?

Comment: No, not really. But changing the field type works for me. I suspect there are some issue in mongodb driver or Morphia

Comment: Yup, this sorted my issue as well. In my case it was a field with type Decimal128 which needed to change.

Answer (score 8):

Most of the time this is a result of timeouts with long reads\writes.

try to increase the timeouts or remove them completely:

```
    MongoClientOptions.Builder options_builder = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();
    options_builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(<some_long_time>);
    MongoClientOptions options = options_builder.build();
    MongoClient mongo_db = new MongoClient ("your.db.address", options);
```

Comment: It is a write to save a very small object, I don't want to workaround this issue by tuning the connection timeout value. I need to understand why it takes long time if what you said is the direct cause.

Comment: Please add some more info: Any other writes are working? Why using transaction? Why you are setting the same transaction twice with New?

Comment: Updated. `Transaction` is just a data model, not SQL Transaction. Good spot on two new Transaction. I should fix that. Actually the first new Transaction is used to print out the debug information, it was not there originally. But it doesn't impact the result

Comment: You run Query before the update? this might slow down the update.

Comment: Have you tried maybe timing individual calls in `MODEL_TYPE.save`? maybe even stepping with the debugger and see if any call takes long time to compleat unexpectedly? that might point us to a more specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason is the compatibility version is set too low.

Try db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/

Comment: I confirm, that i had same exception with `BigDecimal` when CompatibilityVersion lower 3.4